# Power BI Desktop turns white when browsing a bit

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, tableau

I have a really tiny Power Bi application, 32bit, getting about 800 lines from a single table with about 200 columns.
The size of the app is less than 1 MB.

Whenever I browse for about 30 seconds I get a completely white screen and then I need to kill it through the task manager. Then I can browse for another 15 seconds.

I am using the following visuals:

- filled map - 1 time
- table - 2 times
- card - 4 times

The language settings are all set to English(US), the Options>Preview Features are deselected.
Reinstalled the app, did not help. Any useful ideas?

Comment: Do you have enough RAM?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - 8 GB, i5-8365U, should be enough.

Comment: When running PowerBi, how much memory is used/left?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - does not go above 66% - 5.0/7.6 GB. And this issue only occurs, when some kind of map visual is put. If it is transferred to a matrix, it runs like a normal program, without the white screen.